# Maximum Likelihood Problem of a variation of a Poisson random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I currently have to solve exercise 3.2.

Can someone give me a hint on how to come up with a solution for 3.2? It should be similar to 3.1, which I have solved, not?

3.1. Given a realization (observation) $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of these (Poisson $(\lambda)$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$) find the maximum likelihood estimate of $\lambda.$

$$\begin{align}
L(\lambda) &= P(x_1,\dots,x_n)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n P(x_i)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x_i}}{x_i!}\\
&=e^{-n\lambda} \lambda^{\sum x_i}\frac 1 {\prod x_i!}
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\begin{align}
\log(L(\lambda))&=\log\left(e^{-n\lambda}\right)\log\left( \lambda^{\sum x_i}\right)\log\left(\frac 1 {\prod x_i!}\right)\\
&=-n\lambda +\sum x_i \log \lambda + \log \frac{1}{\prod x_i!}
\end{align}$$

Getting the maximum,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\log(L(\lambda))}{d\lambda}&=-n+\frac{\sum x_i} \lambda + 0\\
&\implies \lambda= \frac{\sum x_i} n
\end{align}$$

3.2. Assume that we only observe events $X_i=0$ or $X_i>0$ for each random variable. Given a realization $y_i,\dots, y_n$ of these events ($y_i=0$ if $x_i=0$ and $y_i=1$ if $x_i>0$), find the MLE of $\lambda.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

So the probability of getting $y_i=1$ can be considered a success of a Bernoulli experiment. And this $\Pr(Y_i=1)=1- \Pr(X_i=0) = 1-\exp(-\lambda).$

The [MLE of a Bernoulli](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/node/28/) rv is the same as for a Poisson - the mean of the sample, which corresponds to the estimated probability of success.

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\bar y&=1-\exp(-\lambda)\\[2ex]
\lambda&=-\log \left(  1 -{\bar y}\right). 
\end{align}$$

This seems to hold on a quick simulation:

```
set.seed(561)

m = matrix(0,12,2)

for(i in 1:12){
l = i
n = 1e6
sam = rpois(n,l)
ybar = mean(sam!=0)
m[i,1] <- i
m[i,2] <- round(-log(1-ybar), 3)
}
plot(1:12, m[,2], xlab="λ", ylab= "Estimated λ", main="MLE", pch=19, col='tan4')
```

[image]